# How to access jupyter notebook from docker on server?

Tags: azure, docker, tensorflow, jupyter

I am using a azure instance called NC6 that has a GPU on it. I want to use a tensorflow docker image that can use this GPU that also spins up a jupyter notebook.

I use this command

`nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`

When I run this command from within the instance I get

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=4c495089418941ad470cfe33b002bd6fad67970f84354e29
```

But when I access the :8888 there is nothing. How can I expose this port to be able to access the notebook from outside the instance?

Comment: Hi, do you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Although I never used Azure instances I think you have to do the following things:

- Open port 8888 of your azure instance to the outside world (this is probably called a service).
- Find the IP of you instance (probably defined in this service)
- Navigate to http://IP_HERE:8888/?token=4c495089418941ad470cfe33b002bd6fad67970f84354e29

Hope this helps!